# What is the best way to post data to an aspx page from WPF application?

Tags: asp.net, http, post, get

I need to send a simple variable value from my WPF app to an aspx page. The page runs under an anonymous web site. What are the best practices to post a single value and read it out on the other side (aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you are looking for is the [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) class.

Just set the post data (or get if it's easier) and execute the request.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to create a web service on that site and call the web service method from the WPF application. To eliminate the web overhead you could use a WCF service instead, hosted on the same server as the ASPX application.

Comment: Why? Can't I just get away with WebRequest & WebResponse .net classes?

Comment: Sure, you could pass your value as a parameter in the querystring, and have your ASPX page handle the parameter on page load. But from an architectural standpoint using a service is cleaner and not really more overhead. You can add the web service to the same solution as your web project.